# nano editor UnJustify

Tags: nano

I'm using nano editor to edit my server's config files. Now I've discovered that pasting in a few lines removes all line breaks of the pasted lines as well as the following lines! It then says I can UnJustify that again. What?! Is this Microsoft Word auto formatting?

How can I prevent this from happening ever again?

UnJustify doesn't work, it only restores part of the broken text, not all.

This is Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: I mainly use servers and only use nano and have never seen your issue. I can only assume that, somehow, your nano sessions are defaulting to justify mode. Check `/etc/nanorc` and the files it might include, such as `/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc`.

Comment: @DougSmythies What would I be looking for in these files? I couldn't identify anything interesting.

Comment: I don't know, I can not find such a setting either. I did find (this)[https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715288], but it has not been my experience.

Comment: That bug is exactly the issue! CR, LF corresponds to ^J, ^M. And ^J is a hotkey. Very unfortunately placed. For a unix system. Interestingly, the combination of ^J and ^M won't trigger justify. Heading over to nano now.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on `Raspbian stretch`. Very annoying to paste ssh keys.

Answer (score 1):

Adding below to `~/.nanorc` did the trick for me:

```
unbind ^J main
```

I think it breaks the justify, but I'm more than glad to give it for clean paste.